# using jQuery to find elements ordering when the elements are inside different parent elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something like this:

```
<div>
    <ul id="ul_element_id">
        <li>
            <a id="first"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="second"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="third"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Is there a quick way to figure out $('#first') is the first guy in relation to other  elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like the following:

```
$("a").index($("#first"))
```

That will return 0 since "#first" is the first in the list.  If you did:

```
$("a").index($("#second"))
```

you would get 1.  If you wanted you could just add 1 to whatever value is returned as long as the returned value is not -1.

Also you can change the $("a") selector to whatever you wanted.  Something like $("#ul_id a") would work just fine too.

You can pass any selector to the index method to search a collection and have it return the index of the found element.

http://api.jquery.com/index/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for a combination of two APIs:

closest: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

find: http://api.jquery.com/find/

You can use them both to get to '#first' by using the following:

```
// 'this' being the 'third' link
this.closest('ul').find('#first');
```

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry for not describing the question clearly.  I don't actually need to find the element.  I just need to find their "index" in relation to other <a> programmatically.